# como crear un modulo personalizado con crudbooster?

Tags: php, laravel

Como hacer un modulo personalizado con la herramienta de crudbooster y que este me envié a una pagina externa donde realizara unas operaciones y por ultimo devuelva a la pagina donde estaba antes.

```
use Session;
use Request;
use DB;
use CRUDBooster;

class AdminEncuestas19Controller extends \crocodicstudio\crudbooster\controllers\CBController {

    public function cbInit() {

        # START CONFIGURATION DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE
        $this->title_field = "codigo";
        $this->limit = "20";
        $this->orderby = "codigo,desc";
        $this->global_privilege = false;
        $this->button_table_action = true;
        $this->button_bulk_action = true;
        $this->button_action_style = "button_icon";
        $this->button_add = true;
        $this->button_edit = true;
        $this->button_delete = true;
        $this->button_detail = true;
        $this->button_show = true;
        $this->button_filter = true;
        $this->button_import = false;
        $this->button_export = false;
        $this->table = "Encuestas";
        # END CONFIGURATION DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE

        # START COLUMNS DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE
        $this->col = [];
        $this->col[] = ["label"=>"Codigo","name"=>"codigo"];
        $this->col[] = ["label"=>"Cod Facultad","name"=>"cod_facultad"];
        $this->col[] = ["label"=>"Cod Dependencia","name"=>"cod_dependencia"];
        $this->col[] = ["label"=>"Nombre","name"=>"nombre"];
        $this->col[] = ["label"=>"Fecha Ini","name"=>"fecha_ini"];
        $this->col[] = ["label"=>"Fecha Fin","name"=>"fecha_fin"];
        $this->col[] = ["label"=>"Tipo User","name"=>"tipo_user"];
        # END COLUMNS DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE

        # START FORM DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE
        $this->form = [];
        $this->form[] = ['label'=>'Codigo','name'=>'codigo','type'=>'text','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10'];
        $this->form[] = ['label'=>'Facultad','name'=>'cod_facultad','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10','dataenum'=>'Administración de Empresas;   Administración de Empresas Publica;Arquitectura y Diseño;Bellas  Artes'];
        $this->form[] = ['label'=>'Dependencia','name'=>'cod_dependencia','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10','dataenum'=>'Sede Central;Arraijan'];
        $this->form[] = ['label'=>'Nombre','name'=>'nombre','type'=>'text','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10'];
        $this->form[] = ['label'=>'Fecha Ini','name'=>'fecha_ini','type'=>'date','validation'=>'required|date','width'=>'col-sm-10'];
        $this->form[] = ['label'=>'Fecha Fin','name'=>'fecha_fin','type'=>'date','validation'=>'required|date','width'=>'col-sm-10'];
        $this->form[] = ['label'=>'Tipo User','name'=>'tipo_user','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10','dataenum'=>'Estudiantes;Docentes;Administrativos'];
        $this->form[] = ['label'=>'Estado','name'=>'estado','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10','dataenum'=>'Borrador; Publicada; Archivada'];
        # END FORM DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE

        # OLD START FORM
        //$this->form = [];
        //$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Codigo','name'=>'codigo','type'=>'text','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10'];
        //$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Facultad','name'=>'cod_facultad','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10','dataenum'=>'Administración de Empresas;     Administración de Empresas Publica;Arquitectura y Diseño;Bellas  Artes'];
        //$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Dependencia','name'=>'cod_dependencia','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10','dataenum'=>'Sede Central;Arraijan'];
        //$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Nombre','name'=>'nombre','type'=>'text','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10'];
        //$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Fecha Ini','name'=>'fecha_ini','type'=>'date','validation'=>'required|date','width'=>'col-sm-10'];
        //$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Fecha Fin','name'=>'fecha_fin','type'=>'date','validation'=>'required|date','width'=>'col-sm-10'];
        //$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Tipo User','name'=>'tipo_user','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10','dataenum'=>'Estudiantes;Docentes;Administrativos'];
        //$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Estado','name'=>'estado','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|min:1|max:255','width'=>'col-sm-10','dataenum'=>'Borrador; Publicada; Archivada'];
        # OLD END FORM

        /* 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Sub Module
        | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
        | @label          = Label of action 
        | @path           = Path of sub module
        | @foreign_key    = foreign key of sub table/module
        | @button_color   = Bootstrap Class (primary,success,warning,danger)
        | @button_icon    = Font Awesome Class  
        | @parent_columns = Sparate with comma, e.g : name,created_at
        | 
        */

        $this->sub_module = array();


        /* 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Add More Action Button / Menu
        | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
        | @label       = Label of action 
        | @url         = Target URL, you can use field alias. e.g : [id], [name], [title], etc
        | @icon        = Font awesome class icon. e.g : fa fa-bars
        | @color       = Default is primary. (primary, warning, succecss, info)     
        | @showIf      = If condition when action show. Use field alias. e.g : [id] == 1
        | 
        */
        $this->addaction = array();


        /* 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Add More Button Selected
        | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
        | @label       = Label of action 
        | @icon        = Icon from fontawesome
        | @name        = Name of button 
        | Then about the action, you should code at actionButtonSelected method 
        | 
        */
        $this->button_selected = array();


        /* 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Add alert message to this module at overheader
        | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
        | @message = Text of message 
        | @type    = warning,success,danger,info        
        | 
        */
        $this->alert        = array();



        /* 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Add more button to header button 
        | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
        | @label = Name of button 
        | @url   = URL Target
        | @icon  = Icon from Awesome.
        | 
        */
        //$this->index_button = array();



        /* 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Customize Table Row Color
        | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
        | @condition = If condition. You may use field alias. E.g : [id] == 1
        | @color = Default is none. You can use bootstrap success,info,warning,danger,primary.        
        | 
        */
        $this->table_row_color = array();                 


        /*
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | You may use this bellow array to add statistic at dashboard 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | @label, @count, @icon, @color 
        |
        */
        $this->index_statistic = array();



        /*
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Add javascript at body 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | javascript code in the variable 
        | $this->script_js = "function() { ... }";
        |
        */
        $this->script_js = NULL;


        /*
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Include HTML Code before index table 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | html code to display it before index table
        | $this->pre_index_html = "<p>test</p>";
        |
        */
        $this->pre_index_html = null;



        /*
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Include HTML Code after index table 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | html code to display it after index table
        | $this->post_index_html = "<p>test</p>";
        |
        */
        $this->post_index_html = null;



        /*
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Include Javascript File 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | URL of your javascript each array 
        | $this->load_js[] = asset("myfile.js");
        |
        */
        $this->load_js = array();



        /*
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Add css style at body 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | css code in the variable 
        | $this->style_css = ".style{....}";
        |
        */
        $this->style_css = NULL;



        /*
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Include css File 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | URL of your css each array 
        | $this->load_css[] = asset("myfile.css");
        |
        */
        $this->load_css = array();


    }

    /*
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | Hook for button selected
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | @id_selected = the id selected
    | @button_name = the name of button
    |
    */
    public function actionButtonSelected($id_selected,$button_name) {
        //Your code here

    }


    /*
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | Hook for manipulate query of index result 
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | @query = current sql query 
    |
    */
    public function hook_query_index(&$query) {
        //Your code here

    }

    /*
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | Hook for manipulate row of index table html 
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    |
    */    
    public function hook_row_index($column_index,&$column_value) {          
        //Your code here
    }

    /*
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | Hook for manipulate data input before add data is execute
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | @arr
    |
    */
    public function hook_before_add(&$postdata) {        
        //Your code here

    }

    /* 
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | Hook for execute command after add public static function called 
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | @id = last insert id
    | 
    */
    public function hook_after_add($id) {        
        //Your code here

    }

    /* 
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | Hook for manipulate data input before update data is execute
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | @postdata = input post data 
    | @id       = current id 
    | 
    */
    public function hook_before_edit(&$postdata,$id) {        
        //Your code here

    }

    /* 
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | Hook for execute command after edit public static function called
    | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
    | @id       = current id 
    | 
    */
    public function hook_after_edit($id) {
        //Your code here 

    }

    /* 
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | Hook for execute command before delete public static function called
    | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
    | @id       = current id 
    | 
    */
    public function hook_before_delete($id) {
        //Your code here

    }

    /* 
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    | Hook for execute command after delete public static function called
    | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
    | @id       = current id 
    | 
    */
    public function hook_after_delete($id) {
        //Your code here

    }



}
```

Comment: Laravel no tiene ni crea módulos, ¿a qué te refieres?

Comment: estoy utilizando crudbooster, pero no veo la forma de agrear un modulo de pagina externa desde el listado donde se encuentra editar y eliminar.

Comment: Vuelvo y pregunto, ¿a qué te refieres con módulos? ese concepto NO existe en Laravel.

Comment: Dentro de crudbooster el modulo consiste en un controller con sus diferentes operaciones. Revisa ese sitio crudbooster.com

Comment: Y si mejor haces el crud manual? Otra cosa: qué tipo de operaciones quieres realizar? Si tienes el código o más detalles entonces deberías agregarlos a tu pregunta para que te ayuden mejor.

Comment: ok, ya lo ingreso a la pregunta.

Comment: Ya ingrese el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revisa esto: [How To Add More Action Button In Grid Data](https://github.com/crocodic-studio/crudbooster/blob/5.4.0/docs/en/how-add-more-action-button.md)

En este punto del código agrega un botón personalizado con un enlace al sitio donde quieres redirigir:

```
/* 
        | ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        | Add More Action Button / Menu
        | ----------------------------------------------------------------------     
        | @label       = Label of action 
        | @url         = Target URL, you can use field alias. e.g : [id], [name], [title], etc
        | @icon        = Font awesome class icon. e.g : fa fa-bars
        | @color       = Default is primary. (primary, warning, succecss, info)     
        | @showIf      = If condition when action show. Use field alias. e.g : [id] == 1
        | 
        */
        $this->addaction[] = [
           'label'=>'SetActive',
           'url'=>'ruta-a-tu-pagina-externa',
           'icon'=>'fa fa-check',
           'color'=>'success',
           'showIf'=>"[status] == 'pending'"];
```